# How to pass--skip-host-cache as an ENV argument to the mysql docker container

Tags: mysql, docker

How to pass--skip-host-cache as an ENV argument to the mysql docker container. We see the following error, but don't want to override the conf file, is there to pass as an ENV variable instead

```
The syntax '--skip-host-cache' is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. Please use SET GLOBAL host_cache_size=0 instead.
```

Comment: "SET GLOBAL host_cache_size=0" is a query no?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As its [part of the default configuration](https://github.com/docker-library/mysql/blob/master/8.0/config/conf.d/docker.cnf#L2) in the container creating a [new issue](https://github.com/docker-library/mysql/issues) to remove it seems to be the best option to remove it before their next release.